# Comparing two documents for all occurences of words

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project, where I would need to compare two text documents, for all occurrences of words in document 1, to be repeated in document 2, irrespective of the position of the words. eg, if document 1, contains a passage with 10 occurrences of the word 'in', document 2 must contain 10 occurrences of 'in' too. No problem if the words are placed in different positions. How do I do that??..... thanks in advance.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Build a `Map<String,Integer>` where you count the number of occurrences for each word. If the map for two documents are equal, you have "matching documents".

```
 Map<String,Integer> docToMap(String[] document) {
   Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
   for (String s:document) {
      Integer n=map.get(s);
      n= n==null?1:(n+1);
      map.put(s,n)
   }
 }
```